# How to get the selected option value from select inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html code

```
<div id="BrokersList4ServiceEndWrapper">
  <select id="BrokersList4ServiceEnd">
   <option value="1">s1</option>
   <option value="2">s2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I tried to

1. set the selected value to 1.
2. get the value of the second option.
3. get the selected value

in jquery but didnt get it right and please adive if there is any method to know the selection syntax easily

Comment: Maybe dive into the documentation here for a start: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: [Please use google. Google is a powerful tool. This is your question title googled.](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+get+the+selected+option+value+from+select+inside+div&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS513US514&oq=How+to+get+the+selected+option+value+from+select+inside+div&aqs=chrome..69i57.1495j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+get+the+selected+option+value+in+jquery&safe=off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***set the selected value to 1.***

```
$('#BrokersList4ServiceEnd').val(1);
```

***get the value of the second option.***

```
$('#BrokersList4ServiceEnd option:eq(1)').val()
```

***get the selected value***

```
$('#BrokersList4ServiceEnd').val()
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MVfqD/)

Comment: I have add third question ,please check

Comment: @dhyabi you do realize that all your questions are incredibly basic, and already answered on this site, if not all over the internet? Utilize your tools!

Comment: [lmgtfy links are not allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links), please don't add them to the answer.

Comment: @Juhana i would not rolled back that edit, if you would have commented this before.. I believe commenting is a kind of mannerism before doing a massive change to other's answers. Anyway thanks for that link..